# intercept versus try/catch

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm converting scala 'try/catch' testing code to use 'intercept'

Are there any scenarios where I should not use 'intercept' ? The only benefit of using 'intercept' instead of 'try/catch' is conciseness ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the practical advantages, is that `intercept` also returns an `Exception`, so you can check it like this:

```
intercept[IndexOutOfBoundsException](s charAt -1).getMessage should be === "..."
```

Answer (score 8):

I think the main difference is that `intercept` has a semantic that the exception you got is expected, and not cause by program error.

So I normally only use `intercept` when the test case it to test exception will throw correctly when user input it incorrect or similar scenarios.